# form.isValid() always return false in custom registration form django

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I'm trying to make a custom user registration form in django but I can't understand why the method isValid() always return false please help me!

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'gender',
        'birth_date',
        'country',
    ]
    labels = {
        'email':'Correo Electrónico',
        'first_name':'Nombre',
        'last_name':'Apellido',
        'gender':'Sexo',
        'birth_date':'Fecha de Nacimiento',
        'country':'País'
    }

    widgets = {
        'birth_date' : forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1930,2010)),
        'gender' : forms.RadioSelect(),
        'country' : CountrySelectWidget()
    }
```

[This is my views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYcZl.png)

[This is my register.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPPGS.png)

Comment: you should post the code of the view instead of an image

Comment: Yes, I know but the editor doesn't allow me... I need help now so ... please. Do you know what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_vaild()：
       ....
   else:
       # don't new form
       print(form.errors.as_text()) 
       return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'register': form})
```

then you will see why form is always is not vaild in terminal.

Comment: Thanks ! I got a solution !